# Unable to create ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor project with MonoDevelop on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-14.04

Normally I develop with Visual Studio but yesterday I installed the new Ubuntu (I believe it is 14.04) hoping to try MonoDevelop (installed from Ubuntu repository version 4.x) and create some project in ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor). Unfortunately I got this error on project creation:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:Could not find file “/usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/Templates/Common/Index.cshtml”.
File name:’/usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/Templates/Common/Index.cshtml’
```

There are some posts on SO which recommend to install the latest version from github (5.x), so I did so. 
However now, the previously available option to create a new project in ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor) is gone.

Has anyone run into the same problem and found a workaround? 
Am I missing something?